# elastic search autocomplete, searching with space creating an issue

Tags: elasticsearch

i have indexed my technology database using Edge N gram.i have used following code.

```
 {"settings": { 
    "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
             "standardWithEdgeNGram": {
                 "tokenizer": "standard",
                 "filter": ["lowercase", "edgeNGram"]
             }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
             "standard": {
                 "type": "standard"
             }
         },
         "filter": {
             "lowercase": {
                "type": "lowercase"
            },
            "edgeNGram": {
                "type": "edgeNGram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 15,
                "token_chars": ["letter", "digit","punctuation","whitespace","symbol"]
            }
        }
    }},"mappings": { "technologies":{
     "properties":{
                "application": {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"

        }

      }

  }
}
```

with this code i am able to search for the content.but my issue is when i search for content with space it is not generating required result.

for example
if i search for "ruby" i get output as "ruby on rails" but if i search "ruby ser" it gives an output such as "ruby on rails","windows server" etc but it should basically give me no output....plzzz help

Answer (score 0):

**application**" in the above code is **not_analyzed** which means the content would not be tokenized, hence when you search for "ruby" or "ruby ser" both should give no results as the value is stored as "ruby on rails"

Are you using elasticsearch's head plugin to run the query using "GET"? 
If yes try using **POST**, GET has an issue with ES head plugin, it seems with GET the body is not sent to elasticsearch, since sending an empty _search request returns all the records in the index which is happening in this case.

If you want to use GET with ES head plugin then try merging the query with the _search parameter with _source like below :

```
    _search?source={"query":{"match":{"application": "ruby rails"}}}
```

Have a look at the URI request, which allows you to send basic queries using the **q** parameter within the URI.